# Are there any POS coin open source mobile wallets implementations?

Tags: wallet, android, spv, mobile, proof-of-stake

Specifically, I'm interested in the thick clients with Simplified Payment Verification. Haven't found these so far, do they even exist? Why are the POS mobile wallets such poorly distributed comparatively to the POW coins?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU, PoS is considered flawed by large parts of the cryptocurrency community.

I've not kept abreast of POS coins, but some that I could think of are Peercoin, NXT and Blackcoin, which are currently ranked 38, 39, and 58 on Coinmarketcap.

Unless I'm missing some new more popular ones, I'd say there is less software for them because they have less of an ecosystem / they are less popular?

Comment: Thanks you very much. Could you share some details about the reasons for such opinion? Trying to dive into that, I haven't found any serious solid claims for that. If that is a subject for another question, I will create one.

Comment: @Polyakoff: There is a question here, but the answers aren't too great: [What are the downsides of proof of stake?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/25743/5406). Essentially, it doesn't guarantee to come to consensus when people are trying to attack it, because no one has to commit to mining only on one branch of a blockchain fork. You could mine on every branch, because it doesn't cost you anything to mine.